# How to solve this corrupt file error in ggplot2?

Tags: ggplot2

I get an error of a corrupt file of ggplot2 with this code:

```
spiderplot<-ggplot(SpiderLong, aes(Group, Anxiety))
spiderplot

Error in fetch(key) : 
  lazy-load database 'C:/Users/radam/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3/ggplot2/help/ggplot2.rdb' is corrupt

spiderplot+geom_boxplot()
```

How to solve this?

I tried the code above mentioned.